# Access to user's (hashed) Apple ID

Tags: ios

For an App I'm working on, we're considering part of an organisation's pricing being based on the number of users an organisation has. For this, we'd need some mechanism to ensure that a user's login isn't shared within an organisation.

One approach would be to use `UIDevice.currentDevice.identifierForVendor`, but this wouldn't allow a user to be signed in with more than one device.

I wondered if there is some way to access an anonymised version of the user's Apple ID, hashed and salted with our vendor ID (and even application ID) so that it doesn't allow for tracking and introduce privacy concerns.

Using this at login would restrict a user account to only be used by devices having the same Apple ID, which would be a good enough protection against account sharing, I think.

If not – any thoughts on how else we might add a per user component to pricing?

Thanks.

Comment: Why simply sell through the b2b program?  You can then negotiate a price for the customer and then you don't need to worry about how they distribute it.

Comment: We usually do negotiate with customers at the moment. I'm personally not convinced per user pricing is a great plan, but I think the hope is that restricting like this will help to keep them honest.